Power of a polynomial zeros modulo a prime
I’m an individual with a keen interest in mathematics. I would greatly appreciate any hints, guidance, or suggestions you could offer with the following.
Let $p$ be a prime number, and let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a monic polynomial of degree $n$. Let $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ denote the roots of $f(x)=0$  in $\mathbb{C}$
. Assume that the roots have explicit closed-form expressions. Prove or disprove the existence of an integer $k$ such that
$$
x_j^{p^k} \equiv x_j \pmod{p}
$$
for all $j \in \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$.
If the above statement is true, can it be extended to the case where the roots of $f(x)$ do not have explicit closed-form expressions? Thanks in advance!
Example: Consider $f(x) = x^3 - x + 1$. The zeros of $f(x)$ are the following:
\begin{align*}
x_1 &= -\frac{1}{6} \sqrt[3]{108 + 12 \sqrt{69}} - 2 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{108 + 12 \sqrt{69}}}, \\
x_2 &= \frac{1}{12} \sqrt[3]{108 + 12 \sqrt{69}} 
+ \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{108 + 12 \sqrt{69}}} \\
&\quad + \frac{1}{2} i \sqrt{3} 
\left( -\frac{1}{6} \sqrt[3]{108 + 12 \sqrt{69}} 
+ 2 \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{108 + 12 \sqrt{69}}} \right), \\
x_3 &= \frac{1}{12} \sqrt[3]{108 + 12 \sqrt{69}} 
+ \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{108 + 12 \sqrt{69}}} \\
&\quad - \frac{1}{2} i \sqrt{3} 
\left( -\frac{1}{6} \sqrt[3]{108 + 12 \sqrt{69}} 
+ 2 \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{108 + 12 \sqrt{69}}} \right).
\end{align*}
It turns out that for $p = 101$,
\begin{align*}
x_1^{101} &\equiv x_1 \pmod{101}, \\
x_2^{101} &\equiv x_2 \pmod{101}, \\
x_3^{101} &\equiv x_3 \pmod{101}.
\end{align*}

Are you familiar with finite fields?  Closed forms play no role here.

Could you clarify or suggest a few pointers for reading or review? Thx.
